# Weird angular error when using resource plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my public API resource service as described here:

```
angular.module('fortiguard')
    .factory('API', ['$resource', 'Tools', function($resource, Tools) {

        var Posts = $resource('/api/posts', {
            categories: {method:'GET', isArray:true, url:'/api/posts/categories'}
        });

        var posts_categories = function(next) {
            Posts.categories(function(cats) {
                next( Tools.unlinkArray(cats) );
            });
        };

        return {
            getPostCategories : posts_categories
        };
    }]);
```

Is throwing this weird error when executed

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.posts_categories [as getPostCategories] (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:55101:21)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:54655:13)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:24236:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:24244:27)
    at http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:28513:28
    at link (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:47824:26)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:28270:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:27780:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:27129:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/scripts/compiled.js:27008:30) <ng-view class="ng-scope">
```

When I use Chrome's tools to go to the offending line, im surprised to find it's this one (line annotated below):

```
function consoleLog(type) {
  var console = $window.console || {},
      logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
      hasApply = false;

  // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
  // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
  try {
    hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (hasApply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn.apply(console, args);    // <------------- THIS LINE
    };
  }

  // we are IE which either doesn't have window.console => this is noop and we do nothing,
  // or we are IE where console.log doesn't have apply so we log at least first 2 args
  return function(arg1, arg2) {
    logFn(arg1, arg2 == null ? '' : arg2);
  };
}
```

in the previous item in the stack trace, it's saying theres a problem with this line in my api factory

```
Posts.categories(function(cats) {
```

However, everything works the moment I substitute with this instead:

```
angular.module('fortiguard')
    .factory('API', ['$resource', 'Tools', function($resource, Tools) {

        var Posts = $resource('/api/posts/categories', { <--- CHANGED THIS PATH TO BE THE SAME ONE AS CATEGORIES BELOW
            categories: {method:'GET', isArray:true, url:'/api/posts/categories'}
        });

        var posts_categories = function(next) {
            Posts.query(function(cats) {  <--- CHANGED THIS TO QUERY
                next( Tools.unlinkArray(cats) );
            });
        };

        return {
            getPostCategories : posts_categories
        };
    }]);
```

I'm at a loss for words here, I even copied and pasted from another site I did doing exactly this, and it worked out just fine.

Working with Angular 1.3.13 here

```
bower.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.13",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.13",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.13",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.13",
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the actions object as the second parameter  instead of the third.

This:

```
var Posts = $resource('/api/posts', {
    categories: {method:'GET', isArray:true, url:'/api/posts/categories'}
});
```

Should be like this:

```
var Posts = $resource('/api/posts', {}, {
    categories: {method:'GET', isArray:true, url:'/api/posts/categories'}
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: *slaps self* uuuuuiiugghhhhhhh I KNEW it'd be something simple like that. Thanks! I'll update my code to verify that works tomorrow at work

Comment: Yup, that totally did it

THANK YOU! You're a life saver :D